# Python: Delete all folders except X

Tags: python

I need to delete all folders except 1 specific folder. How do i do this?
This is what i have so far

```
import os, shutil, glob

files = glob.glob('C:\path\to\folder\*')

for f in files:
#DELETE ALL FOLDERS, EXCEPT 1 SPECIFIC NAMED FOLDER
```

Comment: Did you try `if f == 'path of your file': continue else: shutil.rmtree(f)` inside the loop?

Comment: When looping on files, just `continue` when the specific file / folder name is encountered, otherwise delete - it is easy to find on SO or documentation how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import the packages
import os, shutil, glob

# Get the list of files in the mentioned path
files = glob.glob('C:\path\to\folder\*')

# Iterate over files
for f in files:
    # Remove all trailing "\" in cases like "C:\path\to\folder\folder1\"
    # and make it as "C:\path\to\folder\folder1".
    f = f.strip("\\")

    # Split this string by "\" and get the last index element to
    # get the folder name.
    fname = f.split("\\")[-1]

    # Ignore it if it's equal to something you don't want to delete
    if fname != "FOLDER_NAME_TO_IGNORE":
        
        # Delete else
        shutil.rmtree(f)
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @BDL , added the comments